# MATLAB replacing some elements from a vector

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vector

If i have a vector, lets say L=[10;10;10;11;11;13;13] which is associated to another vector X=[1;6;65;34;21;73;14] and I want to create a third vector, Z, with almost all the elements in X, but just replacing a 0 in X when the element (i,j) from L changes. Lets say that the result that I want should look like this Z=[1;6;65;0;21;0;14]

Any ideas how to solve this?

I would be really thankful :)

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

```
X = [1;6;65;34;21;73;14];
L = [10;10;10;11;11;13;13];
Z = X;
ind = [false; diff(L)~=0]; %// logical index of values to be set to 0
Z(ind) = 0;
```

This works by computing a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) `ind = [false; diff(L)~=0]` of the elements where a change has ocurred. The initial `false` is needed because the first element doesn't have a previous one to compare with. The logical index is used to select which values of `Z` should be set to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Z = zeros(length(L))

for i = 2:length(L)
    if(L(i-1) == L(i)
        Z(i) = X(i);
    else
        Z(i) = 0;
    end
end
```